# Need to wait for GSM network response when we send AT+CUSD command

Tags: python, pyserial, at-command

I wrote this code to run USSD, but I am not satisfied with this code. I want to make like I want to wait for modem response.

**Example:** when we dial a USSD code on our mobile the progress bar waiting until the data read from GSM network. I don't like to use `time.sleep()`.

Any idea for me?

```py
def WriteCMDwith_sleep(cmd,sleep):
    ser.write(cmd.encode())
    time.sleep(sleep)
    msg=ser.read(1000)
    msg = msg.decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')
    return msg

WriteCMDwith_sleep("AT+CUSD=1,*2#,15\r",10)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `read_until()`?

Comment: yes, like this. but i cant figure it

Comment: Try playing with it: it allows to read waiting for a specific substring (e.g `"OK\r\n"`). If you need to wait for a set of strings instead of only one, you'll have to perform non-blocking reads concatenating the read bytes and checking time by time if any of the searched string has been found

Comment: I need example of read_until(). how can i implement

Comment: You don't need to implement it is already available: [read_until](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read_until). At this link you also find examples